# At what point will I be allowed to delete my own unanswered question

Tags: support

What level do I have to be? Or how many points?

Comment: You are allowed to delete your own unanswered questions at any time, see [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 4):

If the question is unanswered, you can delete it at any time. You don't need to have a specific amount of reputation.